# Импорт метода/класса из jar файла

Tags: java

Создал test.jar файл проекта. Поместил его в папку libs другого, но не пойму как импортировать классы/методы из этого test.jar. Подскажите пожалуйста, как организовать импорт.
Пытаюсь импортировать следующие классы

```
import com.JSONelements.JSONBaseElement;
import com.parseJSON.BaseParser; 
import com.workWithFile.ReadFromFile; 3 класса(я написал с указанием пакетов)
```

Jar собирал без использовании системы сборки, просто прописал .bat и запустил его, jar файл успешно создался

```
D: 
cd D:\workspace\JSONParser
jar cf parseJSON.jar classFoulder/* src/* 
pause
```

Вообще использую Eclipse, но похоже он не видит классы. Хочу научиться и с помощью Екслипса(без сборщиков) и с помощью командной строки это проделывать. Но статей толковых нет.
Написал это в главном классе нового проекта, но импорт не работает:

```
package com.json;

import com.JSONelements.JSONBaseElement;
import com.parseJSON.BaseParser;
import com.workWithFile.ReadFromFile;
public class TestJSON {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonString = ReadFromFile.readFile("d:/json1.txt");
    System.out.println("Formated from file: " + jsonString);
    JSONBaseElement parserJson = BaseParser.mainParse(jsonString);
    System.out.println(parserJson);
  }
}
```

Comment: используете ли вы какую-нибудь систему сборки?

Comment: Если Вы включите в вопрос пример класса из `test.jar`, который нужно импортировать, то можно будет дать ответ с реальными примерами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В импортируемом `.jar` файле (созданной вами библиотеке) должен точно быть указан `package`, первой строчкой в каждом вашем классе.

Затем, если вы компилируете проект напрямую консольными командами, желаемый `.jar` файл необходимо добавить в `classpath` проекта, который будет использовать нужную библиотеку.

Пример:

```
javac -cp "/путь/до/библиотеки.jar" Проект.jar
```

Тогда в проекте "проект.jar" можно будет использовать библиотеку.

Если вы используете среду разработки **IntelliJ IDEA**, тогда нужно сделать следующее: 
зайти в **Project Structure...** | **Libraries**, нажать **+** и добавить нужную библиотеку в список библиотек: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это делается для того, чтобы вы могли указать `import com.ваш.пэкейдж.ИмяКласса;` в проекте, и при компиляции проект знал, откуда импортировать нужные классы.

С системами сборки всё гораздо проще: если нужная библиотека есть в каком-нибудь из публичных репозиториев, например в `Maven Central`, то достаточно будет указать всего несколько строчек в конфигурационном файле.

Пример для maven: нужно добавить строчки ниже в файл **pom.xml**:

```
<dependencies>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group.id.библиотеки</groupId>
        <artifactId>имя-библиотеки</artifactId>
        <version>версия</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- другие проекты -->
<dependencies>
```

Для **gradle**: добавить строчки ниже в **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'group.id.библиотеки', name: 'имя-библиотеки', version: 'версия'
}
```

И так далее.

Comment: Всё очень хорошо написано, но немного не то что я искал, похоже, раз импорт так просто работает, у меня какие-то проблемы в создании jar файла.

Comment: @GerzogTheBat возможно, но на Ваш вопрос я ответил полностью :) Если проблема, указанная в вопросе, решена, [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), для этого есть галочка слева от вопроса :) Проблему, появившуюся после этого, можете описать в новом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Файл надо поместить в **CLASSPATH** и тогда классы будут доступны для импорта